# How do I validate child properties in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I have model that looks like this:

```
$scope.item = {
    userId: 2,
    bioValues: [{
      name: 'Systolic',
      biometricValue: 120
    }, {
      name: 'Diastolic',
      biometricValue: 80
    }]
  };
```

My form names are "bioValues[0].biometricValue, bioValues[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkGZqKiySFkQyqoY9f3x?p=preview).biometricValue".

But when I try and validate my form, 'ng-show' on my field validation errors isn't triggered.  I have looked at the form object in firebug and all of my applicable form errors are correctly marked as invalid when empty but ng-show isn't triggered.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkGZqKiySFkQyqoY9f3x?p=preview).  Try leaving one of the inputs empty.  The required error is not triggered on ng-show.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to name the fields you are validating the exact name as the model that you are displaying.

[Here is a working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDIu8t?p=preview)

The only change that I made was to name the fields in the template `bioValues1` and `bioValues2`.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form novalidate name="form">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="bioValues1" ng-model="item.bioValues[0].biometricValue" required />
      <span class="error" ng-show="form.bioValues1.$error.required">*Required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="bioValues2" ng-model="item.bioValues[1].biometricValue" required />
      <span class="error" ng-show="form.bioValues2.$error.required">*Required</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    userId: 2,
    bioValues: [{
      name: 'Systolic',
      biometricValue: 120
    }, {
      name: 'Diastolic',
      biometricValue: 80
    }]
  };

});
```

Comment: Sure enough.  I was using indexing in a repeat loop for my naming.  Now I see why that is not necessary.  Thanks so much.  Pulling my hair out on this one.